# How to make docker engine to honour host timezone setting?

Tags: docker, timezone

I am currently adding environment variable `TZ=Asia/Hong_Kong` to every container in a docker-compose file. Is there a global setting on a docker engine level to set the timezone?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will be honored if the system has that timezone by default

```
ENV TZ=Asia/Hong_Kong
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

Comment: Doesn't seems like working for Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. The timezone is configured by dpkg-reconfigure tzdata. Docker engine doesn't honour this config.

Comment: Are your images built on your machine or pulled from some place else?

Comment: Both. For example, [official nginx image](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/nginx/) doesn't seems to be using host tz config.